# Admob shows banner ad, but doesn't show video (Rewarded ads)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

My game successfully shows both banner and video ads on test. Once I change my Ad unit Id to a real one, only banner ads show.

I have published my game less than 24 hours ago, do video ads take more time than banner ads to show?

Comment: This might be because of two reason 1) Because the fill rate in your region might be less 2) Because you might be trying to show video ad before they are actually loaded. You can try and use the listener provided with the SDK. Check if the ad is being loaded or not. If the ad in not being loaded check the error code and google the error code to see what is the issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: @RajeshK Thanks for your reply, I already use if (RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance.IsLoaded())
        {
            RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance.Show();
        }                      
But with no success..

Comment: Is your If loop true? If it is false then use the `onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad` listener and check why the ad is not being loaded. You will get the error code on `onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad`  listener. Log that error code using a toast or log. Find and tell me the error code so that I can help further. Let me know if you need help with  setting up the listeners. Here is the link to listeners documentation https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video#set_up_event_notifications

Comment: There was another person with this same problem yesterday. I recommend you use older version of the plugin. I've seen this solve the issue for others.

Comment: Thank you so much for following up, Rajesh, I was at my friend's today and I tried my game on his phone and video ads did show, but they never showed on my phone or most of my friends. Guess that brings us back to your very first point, fill rate. Thank you so much Rajesh.

Comment: Glad to know that it is working fine. But I would still suggest you to track the error code in you phone so that you are very sure there is no issue from you end. This will help you to improve the quality of you code.

Comment: Im having the similar problem, all works fine on Test Ads & Videos. But when I released it,(with my own IDs) only my Rewarded Video doesnt show. Is it that I just have to wait for a 24-48hrs? All my code is exactly like the AdMob sample. Basically it shows Loading for ever! any further insight?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. For me, rewarded ads didn't load as often as other ads at all. But that's just region-dependent. You also have to wait ~48 hours for them to start showing. (I know this is late but posted for future reference.)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem; in my case, everything was fine on test ads, but only the banner ad was shown once it was published.

I found that to load Rewarded Ads and Interstitial Ads, it's taking more time than a banner ad. So I solved the problem by load the ads once my App is opened.